# as3 Air browse for file on sd card?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

Looking to be able to have access to browse and select a file from the users phone using as3 air.

This code only pops up an upload box and says "No Files were found". But I know I have a zip on my phone so it must not be choosing the right folder path. How can I change that to make it access the entire phone?

```
function unzip_init():void{

    fileFilter = new FileFilter("selected your zip file.", "*.zip; *.gz2; *.bz2;");
    file = new File();
    //file.browseForDirectory("Choose a directory"); // Only got me the directory path
    file.browseForOpen("Open", [fileFilter]);
    file.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, onSelectedFile);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To get all the mp3 files from the SD card

```
var ROOT:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("/sdcard/");
var FILES:Array = ROOT.getDirectoryListing();
var TrackN:int;
var SUBFOLDER:String;

for (var i:int = 0; i < FILES.length; i++)
{
    var File_Ext:String;
    File_Ext = "" + FILES[i].extension;

    if (File_Ext.toLowerCase() == "mp3")
    {
      TrackN++;
      list.addItem( { label:FILES[i].name, data:TrackN, Song:FILES[i].url} );
    }

    if (FILES[i].isDirectory == true)
    {
      SUBFOLDER = "" + FILES[i].nativePath;
      getSubfolders();
    }

    function getSubfolders()
    {
        var SUBF:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath(SUBFOLDER);
        var FLIST:Array = SUBF.getDirectoryListing();

        for (var s:int = 0; s < FLIST.length; s++)
        {
            File_Ext = "" + FLIST[s].extension;

            if (File_Ext.toLowerCase() == "mp3")
            {
                TrackN++;
                list.addItem( { label:FLIST[s].name, data:TrackN, Song:FLIST[s].url} );
            }

            if (FLIST[s].isDirectory == true)
            {
                SUBFOLDER = "" + FLIST[s].nativePath;
                getSubfolders();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the future, please add some comments to your answer so we know what you are trying to say, also, please format your code.  What's with all those $'s?

Answer (score 1):

I gave you an answer here: [as3 get zip file on phone from app - file path then unzip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257626/as3-get-zip-file-on-phone-from-app-file-path-then-unzip)

Basically you have to write your own file browser, help documentation suggests this (however they could built it in). e.g.

```
var rootDirs:Array = File.getRootFirectories();//all available root dirs
```

then you can pick one and lists it's content

```
if(rootDirs && rootDirs.length > 0)
{
    var dir:File = rootDirs[0]
    if(dir.isDirectory)
    {
        //try to enumerate it's content

        var files:Array = dir.getDirectoryListing();

    }
}
```

best regards