# as3 get zip file on phone from app - file path then unzip

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, zip

The following code when run in air works great on the desktop. It allows you to select the file and unzip it and write it.

However, when I run it on my phone only "Audio", "Video" , "Images" files become avail able and I can't access a zip file I want to unzip from my phone.  Here is the full code:

```
import com.coltware.airxzip.ZipEntry;
import com.coltware.airxzip.ZipError;
import com.coltware.airxzip.ZipFileReader;
import com.coltware.airxzip.*;

import flash.filesystem.File;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;
import flash.net.FileReference;
import flash.net.FileFilter;
import flash.filesystem.FileStream;
import flash.filesystem.FileMode;

var file:File;
var fileReference:FileReference;
var fileFilter:FileFilter;
var baseDir:File = File.documentsDirectory;

function unzip_init():void{

    fileFilter = new FileFilter("selected your zip file.", "*");
    file = new File();

    **// This next line did not work and the one below that either. mistakes here!
    //file.browseForDirectory("Choose a directory");**
    file.browseForOpen("file://mnt/sdcard/", [fileFilter]);
    file.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, onSelectedFile);
}

function onSelectedFile(e:Event):void
{

    trace(file.nativePath);
    var reader:ZipFileReader = new ZipFileReader();
    reader.open(file);

    var list:Array = reader.getEntries();
    var i:int = 0;

    for each(var entry:ZipEntry in list)
    {
        var filename:String = entry.getFilename();

        if(entry.isDirectory())
        {

            trace("DIR  --->" + entry.getFilename());
            //  If entry is directory
            var dir:File = baseDir.resolvePath(filename);
            dir.createDirectory();
        }
        else
        {
            trace("FILE --->" + entry.getFilename() + "(" + entry.getCompressRate() + ")");
            var unzippedBytes:ByteArray = reader.unzip(entry);
            //trace("btyes --->" + unzippedBytes);
            var file:File = File.userDirectory.resolvePath(entry.getFilename());
            var fs:FileStream = new FileStream();
            fs.open(file,FileMode.WRITE);
            fs.writeBytes(unzippedBytes,0,unzippedBytes.length);
            fs.close();
        }
    }
    reader.close();
}

unzip_init();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to write your own file browser using flash.filesystem.File class.

Below are few methods from my own FileBrowser class:

```
/**
 * Displays root directories
 */
public function showRootFolders():void
{
    if (!m_oLocation) m_oLocation = new File();
    var rootDirs:Array = File.getRootDirectories();
    if (!m_vRootDirs) m_vRootDirs = new Vector.<File>();

    for (var i:int = 0; i < rootDirs.length; i++)
    {
        var item:File = rootDirs[i];
        if (i < m_vRootDirs.length) m_vRootDirs[i] = item;
        else m_vRootDirs.push(item);
    }

    if (contains(m_oLevelUp)) removeChild(m_oLevelUp);
    m_oFolderName.setLabel("ROOT");
    m_oFolderInfo.setLabel(rootDirs.length + " Folder(s), " + 0 + " File(s)");

    displayList(m_vRootDirs);
}


/**
 * <p>Gets all files from requested location (File) and updates list view.</p>
 * @param    p_oLocation
 * @param    p_bLinkToParent
 */
public function listLocation(p_oLocation:File, p_bLinkToParent:Boolean=false):void
{
    trace("listLocation(p_oLocation:File):void");
    //folder or file
    if (p_oLocation.isDirectory)
    {
                    clear()://clear list view
        var _vItems:Vector.<File> = new Vector.<File>();

        var files:Array = p_oLocation.getDirectoryListing();

        trace("files.length:"+files.length);
        var _nFiles:int = 0;
        var _nFolders:int = 0;

        for (var i:int = 0; i < files.length; i++)
        {
            var item:File = files[i];

            if (item.isDirectory) _nFolders++;
            else _nFiles++;

            _vItems.push(item);
        }

        if (p_bLinkToParent)
        {
            if (p_oLocation.parent != null || m_vRootDirs.length > 0)
            {
                //return button
                m_oParent = p_oLocation.parent;

                addChild(m_oLevelUp);
            }
            else
            {
                if (contains(m_oLevelUp)) removeChild(m_oLevelUp);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            m_vRootDirs.length = 0;
            if (contains(m_oLevelUp)) removeChild(m_oLevelUp);
            m_oParent = null;
        }

        m_oFolderInfo.setLabel(_nFolders + " Folder(s), " + _nFiles + " File(s)");

        m_oFolderName.setLabel(p_oLocation.name);

        displayList(_vItems);
    }
}


/**
 * <p>Display given file list in the list view</p>
 * @param    p_vFileList
 */
protected function displayList(p_vFileList:Vector.<File>):void
{
    trace("displayList(p_vFileList:Vector.<File>):void");
    clear();//clear list view
    //sort
    p_vFileList = p_vFileList.sort(sortByName)
    //[...]
    //build
    var data:Vector.<ListItemData> = new Vector.<ListItemData>();

    var p:Point = new Point();
    for (var i:int = 0; i < p_vFileList.length; i++)
    {
        var item:File = p_vFileList[i];
                    //here do what ever you like with the list of files
                    //e.g. populate the list view with different type based on the file extension, type etc.
        }
}
```

I hope it will help you a bit,

best regards

Comment: Actually at the moment I just need to "point" to a particular file to unzip. I can do it on my desktop but when testing on my phone it won't open the appropiate folder. I don't even need the browse feature at the moment I just need to get the correct path.

Comment: Then you can't on AIR for Android, that is why you have to fake the browse for file functionality.
If you know the location, and it is within user access rights then you will be able to access it with the File object. But surely what you are missing is the freedom of selecting the ZIP, right?

Comment: I would like to try out your file-browser class, however I have encounter some errors when testing with your sample code. As a newbie, I have no idea what are the variable types for these variables that you have used: m_vRootDirs
m_oFolderName
m_oParent
m_oFolderInfo Can you kindly enlighten me? I have been searching hi & low for the method of how to browse and select different file type (other than media file) in Android. Many thanks.