# Flex/air mobile - Display All mp3 Song From the SD card with id3 info and poster image

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, adobe, mp3

I am trying to fetch all mp3 songs from SD card .
I want only the .mp3 files to be displayed and not any of the folders/ sub folders. I need every mp3 song that exists in SD card and how to get ID3 info from loaded mp3 songs.

Your feedback is highly appreciated….

Comment: These are basically 2 seperate questions, so you should ask them as such. cfr. http://stackoverflow.com/faq

To answer your questions 1.Finding all mp3 files on your SD card cfr. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12255418/as3-air-browse-for-file-on-sd-card 2. Getting extensive ID3 support does not work out of the box in AIR. You might have to write a native extension for this.

Comment: Thanks for immediate response.
For the Q1 answer, i have already implement that in my code, but it hangs the mobile device, do you have any other option, that will really help me a lot...

Comment: Yes it will in fact hang the device since AIR is single threaded. Thus any long lasting / heavy operation will hang the main thread. Recursing over all directories and files of your SD card is of course a heavy operation. The only real fix would be to also write a native extension for this that you could call asynchronously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same issue I was searching for! And I think this should help you too pal :)

This is an absolute AIR solution to fetch any file formats from different folders in sdcard.

Try this: http://myappsnippet.com/file-browser-air-extension/